# Effects of single-point and multi-point calls of Point on plot range

Tags: graphics, bugs

**Bug fixed in version 13.2.0 or earlier**

---

Several Graphics primitives are listable. For instance, `Point` accepts lists of coordinates so that multiple calls to `Point` are often unnecessary.

The results are the same, except for one thing I noticed while working on the eye fixation question, yesterday.

```
pts = RandomReal[10, {30, 2}];  
pl1 = Graphics[Point@pts];    (* single Point function call    *)
pl2 = Graphics[Point /@ pts]; (* multiple Point function calls *)

GraphicsRow[{pl1, pl2}, Frame -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The difference lies in the effect on `PlotRange`. Whereas a list of `Point`s yields a `PlotRange` of:

```
AbsoluteOptions[pl2, PlotRange]

(*
==> {PlotRange -> {{0.493385472, 9.588596333}, {0.2849334536, 9.012342799}}}
*)
```

using the multi-`Point` syntax gives:

```
AbsoluteOptions[pl1, PlotRange]

(*
==> {PlotRange -> {{0., 1.}, {0., 1.}}}
*)
```

The Get Coordinates tool gets the same coordinates in both figures.

The question is: is there any good reason for the `PlotRange` reported in `pl1` or is this a bug?

Comment: It's half the extents of the min-max of the individual points... not sure why though.

Comment: @r.m The points lie in a range of 0-10. What do you mean with individual min- max extent?

Comment: `Graphics` plots each point (if you plotted one by one) such that it is centered in the entire plot. So if you do it individually and calculate the `PlotRange` for each, then I would expect that if you `Show[]` all of them, the plot range would span the minimum and maximum among all the individual ones. So far this is good. However, what you see is _exactly_ half of that. I can't explain for this factor of 2 though. Try: `xylims = (Last /@ FullOptions[Graphics[Point@#], PlotRange] &) /@ pts; Through[{Min, Max}@#] & /@ (xylims\[Transpose])`. This final number is twice the plot range for `pl2`

Comment: It's a bug, that has been reported once or twice already.

Comment: Using `Complement[Union[FullOptions[pl2], FullOptions[pl1]], 
 Intersection[FullOptions[pl2], FullOptions[pl1]]]` you find there are additional options that differ between `pl1` and `pl2`:`AspectRatio`,`AxesOrigin`, and `Ticks`.

Comment: @BrettChampion I wasn't aware of that. Was it reported here or on SO?

Comment: @Sjoerd In an email response today, Wolfram confirmed that the 3D analogue in my answer is a known bug.

Comment: @jens Good to know. Any clue as to when a fix will be around?

Comment: @Sjoerd not really - the developers are "working on finding a solution," i.e.: don't call us, we'll call you.

Comment: @jens Anyway, so it's not AbsoluteOptions as you surmised in your answer. If you could modify it a bit to include this information I'll accept your answer

Comment: Actually, it _is_ AbsoluteOptions because the bug report I sent to Mathematica was all about how AbsoluteOptions gives the wrong result with or without using the listablility of Sphere. My statement in the bug report was: "AbsoluteOptions doesn't work properly" and they confirmed it.

Comment: @Jens In that case...

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries The bug is still present in 11.0.1. Do you recall for which version you reported it? I guess 8.0 but perhaps with an earlier version?

Comment: @Xavier it was jens who reported it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm tempted to blame this on `AbsoluteOptions`, because it is known to be buggy (I filed a bug report on it in January). I also tried the following

```
FullGraphics@Show[pl1, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Frame mismatched]

which shows that the incorrect `PlotRange` value is in fact used internally, making this a pretty significant bug.

I would suggest filing a bug report blaming it on `AbsoluteOptions` (it's just a guess, but hey - we don't have the source code...)

**Update**

I think the case against `AbsoluteOptions` is becoming stronger with the following tests. That means, I'm now pretty confident that the issue in this question is *not* inherent to the argument-list version of `Point`.

Consider the three-dimensional version of the question, with

```
pts = RandomReal[10, {30, 3}];
pl1 = Graphics3D[Point@pts];
pl2 = Graphics3D[Point /@ pts];
```

The results of `AbsoluteOptions[pl1, PlotRange]` and `AbsoluteOptions[pl2, PlotRange]` show the same discrepancy as in the 2D case.

If I now replace the 3D points by spheres, I can use the same two methods of feeding it the points:

```
sph1 = Graphics3D[Sphere[pts, .05]];
sph2 = Graphics3D[Sphere[#, .05] & /@ pts];
```

*However*, the results of

```
AbsoluteOptions[sph1, PlotRange]
```

and

```
AbsoluteOptions[sph2, PlotRange]
```

now *both* show the incorrect result `{PlotRange -> {{0., 1.}, {0., 1.}, {0., 1.}}}`. What I would infer from this is that it is *not* the listability property itself that is causing a wrong `PlotRange` calculation. Note: I say "infer" - not "conclude", because it's not conclusive...

**Update 2**

For completeness, I sent a bug report to Wolfram in which I gave these examples and stated that `AbsoluteOptions` doesn't work properly here. Wolfram support confirmed the bug.