# AbsoluteOptions of a Histogram with PlotRange

Tags: options, histograms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mathematica: Retrieving PlotRange from Histogram](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8754/mathematica-retrieving-plotrange-from-histogram)

I would like to evaluate the `AbsoluteOptions` of one of my `Histogram`. In order to make it better-looking, I apply a `PlotRange`. When one of the boundaries is put to `Automatic`, an error occurs, and I don't know how to avoid it.

Here is a minimal example :

```
data = Table[{3 Random[] - 1, 8 Random[] - 4}, {i, 100}];
PlotA = Histogram[Transpose[data][[2]],20, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2.2}, Automatic}]
AbsoluteOptions[PlotA]
```

and the error returned :

```
"Value of option PlotRange -> {{-2,2.2},{All,All}} is not All, Full, 
  Automatic, a positive machine number, or an appropriate list of range 
  specifications."
```

When I replace `Automatic` by fixed boundaries like `{0,50}`, it works. Yet I thought that my use of the command `Automatic` was correct. Where's the problem ?

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, this is a bug.

Comment: Answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9225587/mathematica-retrieving-plotrange-from-histogram

Comment: There have been several issues reported with `AbsoluteOptions` - here is an example I remembered: [Effects of single-point and multi-point calls of Point on plot range](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2744/245) - it's not the same, but it's perhaps worth pointing out how much can go wrong with `AbsoluteOptions`.

Comment: flagged in SO to migrate. Now closing this one as dup