# Mathematica: Retrieving PlotRange from Histogram

Tags: bugs, histograms

**Bug introduced in 10.0 or earlier and fixed in 12.0**

I know that one can retrieve `PlotRange` of a plot by using

```
AbsoluteOptions[plot,PlotRange]
```

but that won't work on `Histogram`. Here an example:

```
In[1099]:=

data = {-1.2056, -1.46192, -1.30053, -2.52879, -0.99636, -1.73904, -1.164,
-1.83398,-0.97505, -0.503256, -0.63802, -0.785963, -0.711821, -0.820439, -1.8699,
-3.9659, -1.4456, -1.67021, -1.42009, -2.5644, -1.45002, -1.27806, -1.66529,
-1.67073, -3.31102, -3.38638};
Histogram[%, PlotRange -> Automatic];
AbsoluteOptions[%, PlotRange]
```

When running the code I get the following message.

```
PlotRange::prng: Value of option PlotRange -> {{All,All},{-4.,0.}} is not All,
Full, Automatic, a positive machine number, or an appropriate list of range
specifications. >>
```

As I understood the documentation, `PlotRange` need to be of a certain format (e.g. two numbers) and `{{All,All},{-4.,0.}}` apparently does not fit to that format, for which reason Mathematica won't give me back the `PlotRange` of my histogram.

Does anybody know how I can get the `PlotRange` of a `Histogram` anyway? By the way: In the first place, it will only make sense to get hold of the second value of `PlotRange` (in my example: `{-4.,0.}`) since one can calculate the first one for instance through `{0, Length[data]}`.

Many thanks!

John

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
data = {-1.2056, -1.46192, -1.30053, -2.52879, -0.99636, -1.73904, \
-1.164, -1.83398, -0.97505, -0.503256, -0.63802, -0.785963, \
-0.711821, -0.820439, -1.8699, -3.9659, -1.4456, -1.67021, -1.42009, \
-2.5644, -1.45002, -1.27806, -1.66529, -1.67073, -3.31102, -3.38638};
hist = Histogram[data, PlotRange -> Automatic]
First[PlotRange /. Options[hist, PlotRange]]
```

Comment: Works perfect. Thank you Rolf!

One more issue appeared after setting the plot range as I wanted it to be. For the second histogram Mathematica draws at the level of the minimum value a line which I cannot get rid of (e.g. by `GridLines->None`). Do you have any suggestions on that issue?

Code:
HistogramFirst=Histogram[data, PlotRange -> Automatic]
HistogramSecond=Histogram[data, PlotRange -> {-8, 0}]

Comment: I do not see such a line. Which Mathematica version and which operating system are you using?

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** getting `PlotRange` in both directions:

```
hist = Histogram[data, PlotRange -> Automatic, BarOrigin -> Left]
```

[image]

```
PlotRange /. Options[hist, PlotRange]
```

> {{All, All}, {-4., 0.}}

To get the values for `{All, All}` is more involved than suggested in OP:

> *it will only make sense to get hold of the second value of `PlotRange` (in my example: `{-4.,0.}`) since one can calculate the first one for instance through `{0, Length[data]}`*

```
{0, Length[data]}
```

> {0, 26}

Obviously not the same as the horizontal plot range in the picture above.

To get plot ranges in both horizontal and vertical dimensions, we can use the functions `prF1`,`prF2`, or `prF3` from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/156783/125) to a closely related Q/A:

```
ClearAll[prF1]
prF1 = Charting`CommonDump`getplotrange[#, AxesOrigin /. Options[#, AxesOrigin]] &;

prF1 @ hist
```

> {{0, 14.},{-4., 0.}}

```
ClearAll[prF2]
prF2 = MinMax/@Transpose[Join@@Cases[ToBoxes@#, RectangleBox[x_, y_, ___] :> {x, y}, ∞]]&;

prF2 @ hist
```

> {{0, 14.}, {-4., 0.}}

```
prF3 = Module[{boundingbox}, 
    Histogram[#, ChartElementFunction -> ((boundingbox = 
          Charting`ChartStyleInformation["BoundingBox"]; 
         ChartElementData["GlassRectangle"][##]) &)]; boundingbox] &;

prF3 @ data
```

> {{0, 14.}, {-4., 0.}}

**Original answer:**

You can also extract the `PlotRange` from the second `Part` of `hist`:

```
PlotRange /. hist[[2]] // First
(* {-4.`, 0.`} *)
```

**Note:** `hist[[2]]` contains the options

```
hist[[2]]
(* {AspectRatio->1/GoldenRatio, Axes->{True,True}, AxesLabel->{None,None}, 
   AxesOrigin->{-4.,0}, FrameTicks->{{Automatic, Automatic},{Automatic, Automatic}}, 
   GridLines->{None,None}, PlotRange->{{-4.,0.},{All,All}},
   PlotRangePadding->{{Scaled[0.02],Scaled[0.02]}, 
       {Scaled[0.02],Scaled[0.1]}},Ticks->{Automatic,Automatic}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use my function [graphicsInformation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138907/45431) to do this:

```
data = {-1.2056,-1.46192,-1.30053,-2.52879,-0.99636,-1.73904,-1.164,
-1.83398,-0.97505,-0.503256,-0.63802,-0.785963,-0.711821,-0.820439,
-1.8699,-3.9659,-1.4456,-1.67021,-1.42009,-2.5644,-1.45002,-1.27806,
-1.66529,-1.67073,-3.31102,-3.38638};

hist=Histogram[data,PlotRange->Automatic]

graphicsInformation[hist]
```

[image]

> {"ImagePadding" -> {{13.7242, 1.5}, {12.7383, 0.5}}, 
>    "ImageSize" -> {360., 226.322}, "PlotRangeSize" -> {344.776, 213.083}, 
>    "ImagePaddingSize" -> {15.2242, 13.2383}, 
>    "PlotRange" -> {{-4.08333, 0.0833333}, {-0.301075, 14.7527}}}

Note that the PlotRange returned is different than that given by the other answers, e.g.:

```
First[PlotRange /. Options[hist]]
```

> {-4., 0.}

Looking at the actual plot, it is clear that the value returned by `graphicsInformation` is more accurate.