# How to extract (absolute) Tick and/or PlotRange specs from output of Histogram?

Tags: graphics, ticks, charts

If, for example,

```
g = Histogram[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 200]];
```

...I want to extract an absolute (abscissa) `Tick` specification from `g`.  (The RHS above is just a convenient example, straight from the docs for `Histogram`.)

`FullGraphics` and `AbsoluteOptions` are basically useless for this.

I also tried to extract an absolute `PlotRange` spec from `g`, but, again, nothing I tried worked.  (The idea here was that, maybe, I could pass the extracted `PlotRange` spec to a suitable dummy `Plot` expression from whose output I may be able to extract an absolute abscissa `Tick` spec from.)

Comment: After examination of `FullForm[g]`: the `PlotRange` can be extracted with `Cases[g, x : Rule[PlotRange, ___] :> x, Infinity]`. The `Rule`s for `Ticks` and `FrameTicks` are, however, expressed in terms of `Automatic`. Interestingly, `AbsoluteOptions[g, PlotRange]` gives the `PlotRange` in the error message, but not as output, though.

Answer (score 5):

> *I also tried to extract an absolute `PlotRange` spec from `g`*:

```
SeedRandom[1]
dd = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 200];
g = Histogram[dd]
```

[image]

**1. Use `` Charting`CommonDump`getplotrange `` with `Options[g, AxesOrigin]`:**

```
prF1 = Charting`CommonDump`getplotrange[#, AxesOrigin /. Options[#, AxesOrigin]] &;

prF1 @g
```

> {{-2.5, 3.}, {0, 45.}}

**2. Post-process the box expressions of `g` to extract the bounding boxes:**

```
ClearAll[prF2]
prF2 = Through[{Min, Max}@#] & /@ Transpose[
     Join @@ Cases[# // ToBoxes, RectangleBox[x_, y_, ___] :> {x, y}, ∞]] &;

prF2 @ g
```

> {{-2.5, 3.}, {0, 45}}

```
Legended[Show[g, GridLines -> prF1[g], GridLinesStyle -> Red, 
  Axes -> False, Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}, 
  PlotRangePadding -> {{3, 3}, {5, 10}}, ImagePadding -> 20, 
  Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> Thread[{Reverse@prF1[g], None}]], 
 Panel[TableForm[prF1[g], TableHeadings -> {{"x", "y"}, {"min", "max"}}], 
  "plot range", Top]]
```

[image]

**3. Inject `` Charting`ChartStyleInformation["BoundingBox"] `` into `ChartElementFunction` option setting:**

```
ClearAll[prF3]
prF3 = Module[{boundingbox}, Histogram[#, ChartElementFunction -> 
 ((boundingbox = Charting`ChartStyleInformation["BoundingBox"]; 
      ChartElementData["Rectangle"][##]) &)]; boundingbox] &;

prF3[dd]
```

> {{-2.5, 3.}, {0, 45}}

**4. Use `` Charting`get2DPlotRange[g] `` and `Options[g, PlotRangePadding]` to compute the plot range:**

The function `` Charting`get2DPlotRange `` gives padded plot range (including `PlotRangePadding` values):

```
Charting`get2DPlotRange[g]
```

> {{-2.61, 3.11}, {-0.9, 49.5}}

The value of the option `PlotRangePadding` is easily obtained:

```
Options[g, PlotRangePadding]
```

> {PlotRangePadding -> {{Scaled[0.02], Scaled[0.02]},{Scaled[0.02], Scaled[0.1]}}}

Given padded plot range and padding information we can solve for the value of plot range:

```
paddingsF = Module[{i = 1}, (-1)^(i++) # & @@@ #] & /@ 
  (PlotRangePadding /. Options[#, PlotRangePadding]) &;

prF4 = Module[{aa = Array[a, {2, 2}]},
    Chop[aa /. First@Solve[aa + (First /@ Differences /@ aa) paddingsF[#] == 
         Charting`get2DPlotRange[#], Flatten[aa], Reals]]] &;

prF4 @ g
```

> {{-2.5, 3.}, {0, 45}}

**Note:** The last method works in version 9, but not in version 11.

Comment: These all fail in different ways when I use them on a `Histogram` with `"PDF"` option.  Modifying `prF2` to: `prF2 = Through[{Min, Max}@#] & /@ Transpose[Join @@ Cases[# // ToBoxes,  RectangleBox[x_, y_, ___] :> {x, y}, \[Infinity]] /. NCache[_, vals_] -> vals] &;` seems to salvage that one though (lightly tested in v10.0 and 12.1).

Comment: @ChrisK, I will post an update if I find a fix  that works in v12.1

Comment: Thanks, but to clarify, that modification I made in my comment seems to work in v12.1.

Comment: Just checked on v12.1 (Wolfram Cloud); `prf2` and `prf3` both work for both `"Count"` and `"PDF"`. (`prF1` and `prF4` look hopeless:().

Comment: Both `prF3[dd]` (modified to add `Automatic` and `"PDF"` in the second and third arguments of `Histogram`) and  `prF2@Histogram[dd, Automatic, "PDF"]` (without modification) give `{{-2.5, 3.}, {0, 0.45}} `.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out when I get back to this mess.

Answer (score 3):

For the [`PlotRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange), you can use my function [graphicsInformation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138907/45431):

```
SeedRandom[1];
g = Histogram[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 200]]

pr = "PlotRange" /. graphicsInformation[g]
```

[image]

> {{-2.61458, 3.11458}, {-0.967742, 47.4194}}

As you say, using AbsoluteOptions to obtain the Ticks doesn't work:

```
Ticks /. AbsoluteOptions[g]
```

> PlotRange::prng: Value of option PlotRange -> {{-2.5,3.},{All,All}} is not All, Full, Automatic, a positive machine number, or an appropriate list of range specifications.
>
> PlotRange::prng: Value of option PlotRange -> {{-2.5,3.},{All,All}} is not All, Full, Automatic, a positive machine number, or an appropriate list of range specifications.
>
> PlotRange::prng: Value of option PlotRange -> {{-2.5,3.},{All,All}} is not All, Full, Automatic, a positive machine number, or an appropriate list of range specifications.
>
> General::stop: Further output of PlotRange::prng will be suppressed during this calculation.
>
> {Automatic, Automatic}

Base on the error message, we can fix this by inserting the [`PlotRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange) manually:

```
Ticks /. AbsoluteOptions[Show[g, PlotRange->pr]] //Short
```

> {{{-2.,-2.,{0.00625,0.},{,AbsoluteThickness[0.25]}},<<27>>,{-2.6,,{0.00375,0.},{,AbsoluteThickness[0.125]}}},{<<1>>}}